# Not getting Google-Drive push notifications

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm following the document https://developers.google.com/drive/push to receive push notifications from Google Drive.

1. My domain is registered (in the API Access pane in the APIs Console).
2. I have a custom program in the registered domain listening over htpps (with a Self-signed certificate). https://myveryowndomain.bc.com/drive/notifications
3. Notification channels are properly created for any change (get response code 200).
4. I make changes in my Google Drive files but nothing comes to *2*, not even the sync message.

**Am I missing something?**

```
CONFIG: -------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/watch
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer 1/QRYL1ZHO4KyUmjkbHVWXCWglxJ5e6-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: push-test-project Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.15.0-rc (gzip)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 150

Jul 24, 2013 6:02:04 PM com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute
CONFIG: curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1/QRYL1ZHO4KyUmjkbHVWXCWglxJ5e6-xxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'User-Agent: push-test-project Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.15.0-rc (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/watch' << $$$
Jul 24, 2013 6:02:04 PM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: Total: 155 bytes
Jul 24, 2013 6:02:04 PM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: {"address":"https://myveryowndomain.bc.com/drive/notifications","id":"f143f7ba-759a-42b8-8748-e39a71ba13cc","type":"web_hook"}
Jul 24, 2013 6:02:08 PM com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse <init>


CONFIG: -------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "RFvxxXV9yoZniidCHgcusodAlXI/AaEAn8d9Ma5bpJZNmM0F72Crxxx"
Content-Length: 247
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Server: GSE
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2013 09:02:08 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Jul 24, 2013 6:02:08 PM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: Total: 296 bytes
Jul 24, 2013 6:02:08 PM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: {
 "kind": "api#channel",
 "id": "f143f7ba-759a-42b8-8748-e39a71ba13cc",
 "resourceId": "_X2yFKJJ6yLq3eIrw3OSxxxxxxx",
 "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes?includeDeleted=true&includeSubscribed=true&maxResults=100&alt=json",
 "token": "",
 "expiration": "1374660126357"
}
```

Comment: Is _Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT_ in the response normal?

Comment: Expires is `Wed, 24 Jul 2013 10:02:06 GMT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-signed SSL seems to be the problem here. It's not only about encryption. It's also about trust issue.
You can get free SSL from [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) or [CACert](http://www.cacert.org/).

FYI, expires header is not expiration time of the channel. It's information about cache. 
Your real expiration time of the channel can be found at "expiration" field of the response body. It is represented in unix time format and your response "1374660126357" is actually "Wed, 01 Apr 45531 03:05:57 GMT". Default expiration time for changes channel is 1 week.

Comment: 1) Would be good if the documentation mention that self-signed certificates are not enough.

2) Even taking into account privacy, and security, for dev purposes setting up a real SSL is a bit too much.

3) Being able to see Google side logs (in the API console or somewhere else) of notification would be great help. e.g., _invalid certificate error_, _notification sent to https://myveryowndomain.bc.com/drive/notifications_