# Unable to receive Google Drive push notifications

Tags: google-drive-api

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831828/not-getting-google-drive-push-notifications). I have exact same issue but I have valid ssl certificate from [thawte](http://www.thawte.com/).I made watch request with only id,type and address properties as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push). My address property looks like, `https://mydomain.me:8443/api/notifications`

I am not getting even sync message. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that your certificate is valid and working? For example, via curl.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the tip.I visited the url through browser from various locations. I didn't get any errors but curl is complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I have ssl certificate for domain 'mydomain.me' but address have port appended(mydomain.me:8443). Hosting it on default port(443) fixed the issue. Thanks to @Eric Koleda, his comment did help in resolving the issue.